# How to control tsc output formatting?

Tags: typescript, output

Sometimes I get this:

```
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
```

Other times I get this:

```
var __awaiter =
  (this && this.__awaiter) ||
  function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) {
      return value instanceof P
        ? value
        : new P(function (resolve) {
            resolve(value);
          });
    }
```

I haven't figured out why but it seems to toggle a lot.  I know many of the changes I'm seeing are when I update a dependency but I believe the snippet above is directly from typescript.  Is there a way to lock down the formatting rule?

Comment: Maybe you ve got a linter that does not exclude the transpiled files ?

Comment: Could be.  I have prettier installed and it formats on save.  I don't explicitly have this file open and when it is open it does not auto-format but prettier could somehow be the culprit.

Comment: Any update ? Did you solved the problem

Comment: I ran it a few times and got the format I wanted -- it has not yet produced the more verbose format.  I did not touch my prettier settings so I'm still not sure why it happens.